# Sitecore Form from Experience Editor

Tags: experience-editor, sitecore-forms

Can someone please tell me if It is possible to add `Sitecore forms` from in `Experience Editor` ?

Comment: Did you try Sitecore doc - https://doc.sitecore.com/xp/en/developers/102/sitecore-experience-manager/add-a-form-to-a-webpage.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can allow `Mvc Form` rendering in placeholder which is available in this location `/sitecore/layout/Renderings/System/Forms/Mvc Form` and then select `form data source`.

[image]